# want to display the download link whenever there is a file to download

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, attachment

my Problem is, like the title say, that i want to display the Download Link to a file only when a file available is...

i dont know where the error is:

```
<?php $doc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true); ?>

<div id="custom_pdf">  

 <a href="<?php echo $doc['url']; ?> "> 

 Download PDF Here  

 </a> 

 </div><!-- #custom_pdf -->
```

This is the normal code.. its work fine, but here it displayed unconditionally... and the Code for conditionally is:

```
<?php $doc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true); ?>

<? if(strlen(trim(<?php $doc['url'] ?>)) > 0) { 
<div id="custom_pdf">  

 <a href="<?php echo $doc['url']; ?> "> 

 Download PDF Here  

 </a> 

 </div><!-- #custom_pdf --> 


} ; ?> // end if
```

and here is somewhere the error, but i dont know where.

Can someone please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP tags are not correctly placed in your HTML code:

```
<?php $doc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true);
if(strlen(trim($doc['url'])) > 0) {
?>
<div id="custom_pdf">  
<a href="<?php echo $doc['url']; ?>">Download PDF Here</a> 
</div><!-- #custom_pdf --> 
<?php } // end if  
?>
```

When you switch from HTML to PHP, you need to open a PHP tag `<?php`, and when you switch from PHP to HTML you need to close the PHP tag `?>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a `<?php` tag when you are already in php

```
<?php 
  $doc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true);
  if(strlen(trim($doc['url'])) > 0) 
  { 
?>

  <div id="custom_pdf">  
     <a href="<?php echo $doc['url']; ?> ">Download PDF</a> 
  </div><!-- #custom_pdf --> 

<?php 
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the Download Monitor plugin. You can setup display configurations including icons. It has analytics and file swapping. You can also check a Force Download option so that files do not attempt to load into a new browser window.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/